# Am I using the BigDecimal class correctly? I could really use someone to double check my code to make sure I'm not making rookie mistakes

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've been working on this for a few days. After getting ridiculous double errors, it seemed using BigDecimal was the way to go. Here's the code:  http://pastebin.com/rpbNJnHH

I've never had to use BigDecimal before, so I was hoping someone here could give it a look over and make sure there weren't any stupid mistakes. I've gone through and checked as much as I could be sure of though.

Edit:  Sorry, this is vague.  So, I was using the double primitive type, but of course doing something like for(double i = 0; i < 1; i += .05) will give imprecise values for i (you'll get things like .0499999999 or .249999999999).  So I switched to BigDecimal.  However, I never used BD before, so I was hoping someone could look over my code and make sure I was using it correctly (i.e. I wasn't losing precision somewhere).  Thanks

Comment: are you getting a specific error message or incorrect result that you suspect is due to the BigDecimal? this question is a little vague, it may help to include some more details of what trouble you are having with BigDecimal

Comment: Can you make the question more specific?  Asking us to check your 100 line program with no other context is not very helpful.  Do some work and whittle down your question please.

Comment: I edited the OP to be more specific.  Thanks for the heads up; it was vague.

Comment: Try to write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: It seems like you might want http://codereview.stackoverflow.com.  StackOverflow is for specific programming *questions*.

Comment: You don't even tell us what this program is supposed to be doing. Voting to close. Please check out this blog on [how to ask a good question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: @Mark, you probably meant http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this code even compiles.

```
for (MyPoint point : prevU.keySet()) {
        BigDecimal x = point.getX();
        BigDecimal t = point.getT();
}

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g2.fillOval(x, t, 1, 1);
```

x and t have to be `int` values and in scope.

I recommend you start with something very simple which compiles and runs correctly, and then add to it slowly.  If you try to change too much at once you are likely to end with an overwhelming mess.

Rather than using double or BigDecimal, I would use int values because this is the type you need at the end of the day and unless your screen has more than 2 billion pixels across or down, you don't need long, double or BigDecimal.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I put up an older version.  Either way, my code compiles fine.  I am not asking to look for Java errors.  I'm asking for someone experienced with BigDecimal to make sure I'm using it correctly (I.e., I'm not losing precision).  I might as well just close this if I can